# How can I use data returned by jQuery selector with templates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

How can I render a template, mustache.js for example, using data returned by a jQuery selector?
Like so:

```
var imgs = $('img'),
    arrayOfImgs = { img : $.makeArray(imgs) },
    template = "{{#img}} <span> {{.}} </span> {{/img}}",
    html = Mustache.render(template, arrayOfImgs);
$('.portfolio').html(html);
```

That doesn't work as `$.makeArray(imgs)` returns array of `img` objects, is there a work around?

Comment: You'll have to return the HTML as string, which is easily done with a `$.map` and returning `this.outerHTML`, but it seems like a generally bad idea to do it that way, and just using `wrap()` seems more appropriate ?

Comment: @adeneo thnx a lot that worked. Just with .map() had to use .get(). The template is a bit more complicated . Span is just for demonstration.
If you'll make an answer will be happy to accept it.

Comment: Sure, I'll post an example !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to return the HTML as string, which is easily done with a $.map and returning this.outerHTML

```
var imgs = $('img'),
    arrayOfImgs = $.map(imgs, function(el) { return el.outerHTML; }),
    template = "{{#img}} <span> {{.}} </span> {{/img}}",
    html = Mustache.render(template, arrayOfImgs);

$('.portfolio').html(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `var imgs = $('img')`. It's already an array of img html tags. I don't know how Mustache works.

Comment: it's actually a jQuery object http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/